# How to get scheduled job time?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a scheduled job which runs at 12:45:00 AM. Now through SP I want to get this time. I am running this query in my SP:

```
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_job
    @job_name = N'Daily Trends',
    @job_aspect = N'SCHEDULES' ;
```

This query shows result with a column

```
 active_start_time
    4500
```

> **Expected Output:**  12:45:00 AM.

Can you please suggest how to show the time with Am/PM.

**Edit:** I am calling this SP from c# code. If anybody can suggest how i can convert the time in proper format in c# code will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the time value seems to be stored as `HHMMSS` with the hour (HH) optional I think you need to check if the length of the string is four chars (or maybe if the value exceeds 115959, whichever is faster). A query like this should work:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN Len(active_start_time) = 4 THEN Cast( 
         Dateadd(minute, active_start_time / 
                         100, '00:00') AS TIME) 
         ELSE LEFT(RIGHT('0' + Cast(active_start_time AS VARCHAR), 6), 2) 
              + ':' 
              + Substring(RIGHT('0' + Cast(active_start_time AS VARCHAR), 6), 3, 
              2) 
              + ':' 
              + RIGHT(Cast(active_start_time AS VARCHAR), 2) 
       END AS [Start time] 
FROM   msdb..sysschedules 
       INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules 
               ON msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.schedule_id = 
                  msdb..sysschedules.schedule_id 
       INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs 
               ON msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id = msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.job_id 
WHERE  msdb.dbo.sysjobs.name = 'Daily Trends'
```

I didn't test it with that many values but I believe it should work, or at least give you a hint on how to proceed. Accessing the `msdb` tables directly might be a bad idea and if I recall right, there are some views that give access to similar information and it could be better to use them.

Answer (score 0):

so, to get the data to look like a HH:MM:SS format, the following SQL would work:

```
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT('0' + Cast(active_start_time AS VARCHAR), 6), 2) 
       + ':' 
       + Substring(RIGHT('0' + Cast(active_start_time AS VARCHAR), 6), 3, 2) 
       + ':' 
       + RIGHT(Cast(active_start_time AS VARCHAR), 2) 
FROM   msdb..sysschedules
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sysjobschedules table however the date will be the same.

This blog should help parse the date/time:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/22/sql-server-find-next-running-time-of-scheduled-job-using-t-sql/